# Autolaunched (Scheduled ) Flow not sending out Email after Last Item in the Loop

Tags: visual-workflow

I am trying to build a flow where it checks for Inactive opportunities over seven days through Last Modified Date. The Get Record Element is followed by a Loop Element and then a E Mail is sent out for notifying the Inactive Opportunities. However when I choose the "After Last Item " in Loop connector to Email Action ,it doesn't send out any email although flow runs without error. It works if I choose "For Each item" but ends up sending many emails which I want to avoid . How do I create a flow to send out only one Email at the end of process with cumulative information and not 40+ emails![image: screenshot of the flow below]

Comment: If you only want to send one email you will need to either iterate over all of your records, grab relevant information from each, and store them in a collection variable to be used in your email. Flows are, IMO, not a great tool for this because this approach is cumbersome and the email action is very limited. You may consider using a Visualforce email template instead where you have a lot more control over the formatting.

Comment: Thanks @nbrown! Will try that route out.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use an unofficial email component that gives you a lot of flexibility. You are able to send emails to a csv string or a collection of email addresses. You can still use this component, but it is not the only solution out there. Send rich text email action does the same trick. Check here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_send_rich_emails.htm&release=230&type=5

Either collect all the email addresses by adding them to a collection or append them to a string adding a comma before every value.

P.S. No, you don't need to do Visualforce.